# "SingleInstanceHost" flag for Silverlight App

Tags: silverlight

I found out some interesting flag named "SingleInstanceHost" for silverlight app, which can be set in Application Manifest File. Msdn says that it "Indicates whether the application has a single instance host".

Can anyone explain what does this flag mean?

My test:

1. If I run my wp7 silverlight app on device WITHOUT this flag, then if I try to run the second app instance from start menu - the system kills the 1st instance and runs the new one.
2. If I run my wp7 silverlight app on device WITH this flag, then if I try to run the second app instance from start menu - the system kills the 1st instance and DOES NOT run the new one.

Strange behavior!

Comment: You can find a [same property in Windows Media Center application platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee525779.aspx).  Is this a clue? I do not know. :) The documentation is very ligh _Indicates whether the application has a single instance host_... MS, please, complete the documentation :D

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 3 introduced a way for applications to communicate between each other, either on the same page or instantiated on a different browser instances (works even with Installed/OOB apps). The communication is performed by sender and receiver classes, which exchange messages through named channels. Each receiver must register a unique name for the channel or an exception will be thrown.

And that’s the trick. Listening on a specific named channel will act like a mutex. By catching the ListenFailed exception you get an option to display appropriate message or launch a different version of the application. All the work is done in App.Xaml.cs file:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
try
{
    receiver = new LocalMessageReceiver("singleinstance");
    receiver.Listen();
    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
}
catch (ListenFailedException)
{
    this.RootVisual = new DuplicateInstancePage();
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand, How your response related to `SingleInstanceHost` flag? Could you please clarify?

Comment: It's the way to have a Single Instance of an SL app but not an explanation of the `SingleInstanceHost` flag.